# How to replace once, of each output of one pattern?

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I want to replace a pattern, i don't know the exact word. I need to replace the first occurance of these words.

Input:-

> For example, this is just{an} example to show my{need}. This para{has}
>   no meaning, just{an} example. Imagine that my{replace} should done in
>   this para. For example, this is just{an} example to show my{need}.
>   This para{has} no meaning, just{an} example. Imagine that my{replace}
>   should done in this para. Some more{text}

Required output:-

> For example, this is Replace_Word example to show Replace_Word. This
>   Replace_Word no meaning, just{an} example. Imagine that Replace_Word
>   should done in this para. For example, this is just{an} example to
>   show my{need}. This para{has} no meaning, just{an} example. Imagine
>   that my{replace} should done in this para. Some Replace_Word

Example pattern `s/\(\w*{\w*}\)/Replace_word/g`

I am a beginner in vim. I know this is wrong. I think, need to use for loop, etc

```
0,/Word_to_find/s/Word_to_find/Replace_word/g
```

Comment: Can your input be on multiple lines, or is it always on one line only?

Comment: It may be one line  or multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source this function, then in your input file buffer do:

```
call ReplaceFirst('\S\+{[^}]*}',"REPLACE_WORD")
```

it should does what you want:

```
function! ReplaceFirst(pat, rep) 
    let end = line('$')
    let pat_dict = {}
    for i in range(1,end)
        let line = getline(i)
        while 1
            let found = matchstr(line, a:pat)
            if found == ""
                break
            endif
            let pat_dict[found] = 0
            let line = substitute(line, a:pat, '','1')
        endwhile
    endfor
    "do replacement 
    for  k in keys(pat_dict)
        execute 'normal! gg'
        execute '/\V'.k
        execute 's/\V'.k.'/'.a:rep.'/'
    endfor
endfunction
```

test here:

[image]

Note that this function is not so generic, if your pattern contains `/`, the function may fail. At least it shows my idea. For those enhancements, you can make it complete.

Comment: Thank you so much Kent &  yolenoyer. @Kent, Could you please document your script, because i don't know more about vim scripting. How values assigned to "pat_dict"?. is it an array?

Comment: @SamjithDasan you can understand `pat_dict` as `hashtable`, so `pat_dict[found] = 0` is the assignment. `found` is the key.

Comment: There's a problem in this script (which could be fixed quickly): line 17, it will replace all first occurences, once per line; this is not the desired behaviour

Comment: @yolenoyer oh, yes. you are right. then in the for loop, we need reset cursor to pos (1,1) and do search()

Answer (score 1):

The following do the trick, but it really could be improved:

```
function! ReplaceFirst(line1, line2, pattern, replace)
    let words = []  " To store all possible patterns
    for i in range(a:line1, a:line2)  " Loop over lines in the desired range
        let line = getline(i)
        let c = 1  " Counter for multiple matches in the same line
        while 1  " For each match in the same line:
            let s = matchstr(line, a:pattern, 0, c)
            if s == ""
                break
            endif
            if index(words, s) == -1  " If this match was not already stored:
                call add(words, s)  " Add this match
            endif
            let c = c + 1  " Go to next match in the same line
        endw
    endfor

    for word in words  " For all found matches:
        call cursor(a:line1, 1)  " Go to the beginning of range,
        call search('\V'.word, 'c')  " Then to the first occurence of the match
        " Replace the first occurence in the line:
        exe 's/\V'.word."/".a:replace
    endfor
endf

" Command that takes two args: first one is the pattern, second one is the 
" replace word:
command! -range -nargs=* ReplaceFirst call ReplaceFirst(<line1>, <line2>, <f-args>)

" Example:
" :%ReplaceFirst \<\w*{\w*} REPLACE_WORD
```